# Archive currently installed files using a NSIS installer

Tags: installation, zip, nsis

I am trying to customize my installer accordingly, so that it looks, wether there are specific folders in the $INSTDIR, which is getting set on a MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY. If it finds these folders, it should compress them and put that archive into a backup-folder under $INSTDIR and set it's name according to the date.

I have searched long to find a solution for this, but I did not find any compression plugins nor did I figure out how to ship a 7zip with it and use that for compression. I am not as fit with NSIS though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code not tested, but it should help...

```
# Bundle 7zip archiver and extract it to TEMP folder
File "/oname=$TEMP\7za.exe" 7za.exe
# If target directory exists...
${If} ${FileExists} "$INSTDIR"
    # Create archive on temp folder
    execwait '"$TEMP\7za.exe" a "$INSTDIR\archive.7z" "$INSTDIR\folder_to_backup"'
${EndIf}
Delete "$TEMP\7za.exe"
```